# Call a custom assertion message from a central in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I am new to jmeter and would like to know if it is possible to call a custom assertion message from a central location.

```
Thread group 1
http sample
 xpath extraction
 custom assertion message

Thread group 2
http sample 1
 xpath extraction
 custom assertion message
http sample 2
 xpath extraction
 custom assertion message
```

The custom message use the xpath extraction to get the response code, if the success message code returned then the custom message is ignored.

If the response code is not a success response, we extract the actual response code and use in the custom assertion message.

I would like to call the custom message from one central location instead.

The custom assertion is below:

```
       if (!"SuccessResponseCode".equals(vars.get("xpathResponseCode"))  && prev_result !=  null){

AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("The response code is "+vars.get("xpathextractionResponseCode").toString()+" and the expected is expectedResponseCode"+ctx.getThreadGroup().getName()+" test case.");
```

}

So I would like to call an external custom message

Custom assertion

Thread group 2
    http sample 1
     xpath extraction
     JS232 - call custom message
    http sample 2
     xpath extraction
     JS232 - call custom message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your Assertion at the same level as [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group).

Assertions follow [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) so this way a single assertion will be applied to all samplers in its scope:

[image: JMeter Assertion Scoping Rules]